# Is there a way to have shorter `_cls` values in mongoengine?

Tags: optimization, database-performance, mongoengine, diskspace

Is there a way to have shorter `_cls` values in mongoengine, apart from making the names of the classes shorter (which would make code difficult to read)?

I was looking for something like this:

```
class User(Document):
    login = StringField(primary_key = True)
    full_name = StringField()
    meta = { "short_class_name": "u" }

class StackOverFlowUser(User):
    rep = IntField()
    meta = { "short_class_name": "s" }
```

If the `short_class_name` meta attribute existed (but I have not found it or anything similar), then we could have this:

```
{ "_cls" : "s", "_id" : "john",
  "full_name" : "John Smith", "rep" : 600 }
```

instead of this:

```
{ "_cls" : "User.StackOverFlowUser", "_id" : "john",
  "full_name" : "John Smith", "rep" : 600 }
```

In this example, this leads to about 20% space saving, and in some cases, it could be even greater.

I guess mongoengine is open source, I could go ahead and code this, but if you know a simpler solution, I would love to hear it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looked into mongoengine's source code I and in most part **MiniQuark** got next hack:

```
def hack_document_cls_name(cls, new_name):
    cls._class_name = new_name
    from mongoengine.base import _document_registry
    _document_registry[new_name] = cls
```

or as class decorator:

```
def hack_document_cls_name(new_name):
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls._class_name = new_name
        from mongoengine.base import _document_registry
        _document_registry[new_name] = cls
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

We see no other way than hacking with the `_class_name` and the `_document_registry`.

When you want to rename a class, you must apply this hack immediately after the class definition (or at least before you define any sub-classes, or else they will have a `_types` attribute with the base class's long name). For example:

```
class User(Document):
    login = StringField(primary_key = True)
    full_name = StringField()

hack_document_cls_name(User, "u")


class StackOverflowUser(User):
    rep = IntField()

hack_document_cls_name(StackOverflowUser, "s")
```

or as class decorator:

```
@hack_document_cls_name("u")
class User(Document):
    login = StringField(primary_key = True)
    full_name = StringField()


@hack_document_cls_name("s")
class StackOverflowUser(User):
    rep = IntField()
```

Comment: Creation works (`StackOverFlowUser.objects.create(login="john", full_name="John Smith", rep=600)`), but unfortunately lookup does not (`User.objects.get(login="john")` raises an Exception `NotRegistered: 's' has not been registered in the document registry`.

Comment: Looking into mongoengine source code, it looks like the `DocumentMetaclass` executes the following code upon creation of the document class: `_document_registry[new_class._class_name] = new_class`.  The `_document_registry` is used later during document lookup.  So changing the `_class_name` *after* the class creation is probably too late (or we would need to hack the _document_registry).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't check this. Your solution looks like working. However this is hack.

Comment: Could you please fix your answer to match mine so that I can upvote it?  I appreciate your help but I cannot upvote your answer as it is now.  I'll delete my answer afterwards.

Comment: I updated my answer with your and add class decorator example that looks a little bit pretty for me.

Comment: +1 Hey thanks tbicr! :-)  I like your decorator syntax (I edited your answer to fix an indentation bug).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so far, the best I could come up with is this.  It works, but I'm sure there must be less hackish solutions...

```
class U(Document): # User
    meta = { "collection": "user" }
    login = StringField(primary_key = True)
    full_name = StringField()

class S(U): # StackOverflowUser
    rep = IntField()

User = U; del(U)
StackOverflowUser = S; del(S)
User.__name__ = "User"
StackOverflowUser.__name__ = "StackOverflowUser"
```

Now when I do this:

```
StackOverflowUser.objects.create(login="john", full_name="John Smith", rep=600)
```

I get this document in the `user` collection:

```
{ "_cls" : "U.S", "_id" : "john", "full_name" : "John Smith", "rep" : 600 }
```

Compared to the standard behavior, this is about 20% space saving.  But I don't like how hackish it is.